# Java use SSL for database connection

Tags: java, mysql, database, ssl, truststore

I am currently making a connection to my database without using SSL.  I now would like to utilize SSL.  The way I have it set up, is my database source is in config.

```
DB_SOURCE=jdbc:mysql://myDatabaseInfo:3306/DB_NAME?
DB_USER=dbUser
DB_PW=dbPw
```

I can get the SSL connection to work by calling my program with the following arguments

```
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=path\to\truststore
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=myPassword
```

I can also get it to work by changing the env variables in the code itself

```
dbSource += "?useSSL=true";
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "path\to\truststore");  
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "myPassword");  
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(dbSource, dbUser, dbPw);
```

However, my goal is to make the SSL connection without making any changes to my code and without having to change the VM arguments I use.  Is there a way I can set my source to include this information?

Something like:

```
jdbc:mysql://myDatabaseInfo:3306/DB_NAME?useSSL=true&trustCertificateKeyStoreUrl=path\to\truststore&trustCertificateKeyStorePassword=myPassword
```

I tried this exactly and it doesn't work, ideally I could just add the info to the config I already have so that I don't have to make changes in more than one place.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

**Suggestion 1:** put your trust store instead of the java's trust store, or import your certificate into the java's trust store: `${java.home}/lib/security/cacerts`

**Suggestion 2:** Write your own driver extending `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver`. Put the SSL configuration into the new code. Although you need to code, but not in the main application. Not sure if it's acceptable for you.

Comment: Regarding #1, that only covers the location of the trust store, I would still need the VM argument to set the password, no?

Comment: If you import the certificates to the java's default trust store, you don't need to set the password. It's 'changeit' :)

Answer (score 0):

According to the security section of the [MySQLConnector documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html), the `trustCertificateKeyStoreUrl` takes as input an URL.

That is, you have to prefix it with `file:` in order to make it work for local files. In other words, you need to set the path to your truststore as `file:path\to\truststore`.

The same goes for `clientCertificateKeyStoreUrl`, if you're using that parameter too.